# Fetching data from a source and saving it to zipped python file

Tags: python, python-requests, shutil

I am trying to fetch huge data around 50GB from a database source and then save it to a zipped python file .

I tried with less data of 5 Gb for testing using 1.requests module and then dividing the data chunk size And iterating over it.
2.Also tried with requests and then shutil.copyfileobj which works but takes 6 hours to copy 5 Gb data .

Any other method I can use which will help to fetch 50 Gb data quickly in less amount of time .

Comment: Use a faster network connection, faster database, a faster storage device, ... .

Comment: Can enable compression on your request headers?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334606/requests-module-and-compression  But yeah otherwise as per Claudio

Comment: Thanks Claudio and Peyret for ur response .